# LVM RAID 5 not resulting in logical volume size expected

Tags: linux, lvm, raid5

I'm having an issue with LVM RAID 5 not allowing me to create a LV that uses the space on all four drives in the VG. What is particulary annoying is that I create fthis very same VG/LV using the same model of drives two years ago on this same system and I don't recall having this problem.

Here's the output of pvs and vgs before I attempt to create the RAID 5 LV:

Output of pvs:

```
PV         VG          Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree 
/dev/sda1  vg_sklad02  lvm2 a--    2.73t  2.73t
/dev/sdb1  vg_sklad01  lvm2 a--    2.73t     0 
/dev/sdc1  vg_sklad02  lvm2 a--    2.73t  2.73t
/dev/sdd1  vg_sklad01  lvm2 a--    2.73t     0 
/dev/sde1  vg_sklad01  lvm2 a--    2.73t     0 
/dev/sdf1  vg_sklad02  lvm2 a--    2.73t  2.73t
/dev/sdg1  vg_sklad02  lvm2 a--    2.73t  2.73t
/dev/sdh1  vg_sklad01  lvm2 a--    2.73t     0 
/dev/sdi2  vg_bootdisk lvm2 a--  118.75g 40.00m
/dev/sdj2  vg_bootdisk lvm2 a--  118.75g 40.00m
```

Output of vgs:

```
VG          #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree 
vg_bootdisk   2   2   0 wz--n- 237.50g 80.00m
vg_sklad01    4   1   0 wz--n-  10.92t     0 
vg_sklad02    4   0   0 wz--n-  10.92t 10.92t
```

The command I used last time to create LV using the same model drives on the same system is:

```
lvcreate --type raid5 -L 8.18T -n lv_sklad01 vg_sklad01
```

When I issue this same command changing the VG and LV target names I get:

```
lvcreate --type raid5 -L 8.18T -n lv_sklad02 vg_sklad02

Using default stripesize 64.00 KiB.
Rounding up size to full physical extent 8.18 TiB
Insufficient free space: 3216510 extents needed, but only 2861584 available
```

This doesn't make sense as I have four drives with a capacity of 2.73T. 4 * 2.73 = 10.92. Subtracting one for parity gives me 8.19T, which is the size of the original LV I have on this system. Banging. My. Head. Against. Monitor.   :?

Grasping at straws, I also tried:

```
[root@sklad ~]# lvcreate --type raid5 -l 100%VG -n lv_sklad02 vg_sklad02
  Using default stripesize 64.00 KiB.
  Logical volume "lv_sklad02" created.
```

This results in a LV 2/3 the size I expect. Output from lvs:

```
LV         VG          Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
lv_root    vg_bootdisk rwi-aor--- 102.70g                                    100.00          
lv_swap    vg_bootdisk rwi-aor---  16.00g                                  100.00          
lv_sklad01 vg_sklad01  rwi-aor---   8.19t                                    100.00          
lv_sklad02 vg_sklad02  rwi-a-r---   5.46t                                    0.18
```

After issuing the above lvcreate command the output of pvs, vgs, and lvs are as follows:

```
[root@sklad ~]# pvs
  PV         VG          Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree 
  /dev/sda1  vg_sklad02  lvm2 a--    2.73t     0 
  /dev/sdb1  vg_sklad01  lvm2 a--    2.73t     0 
  /dev/sdc1  vg_sklad02  lvm2 a--    2.73t     0 
  /dev/sdd1  vg_sklad01  lvm2 a--    2.73t     0 
  /dev/sde1  vg_sklad01  lvm2 a--    2.73t     0 
  /dev/sdf1  vg_sklad02  lvm2 a--    2.73t     0 
  /dev/sdg1  vg_sklad02  lvm2 a--    2.73t  2.73t
  /dev/sdh1  vg_sklad01  lvm2 a--    2.73t     0 
  /dev/sdi2  vg_bootdisk lvm2 a--  118.75g 40.00m
  /dev/sdj2  vg_bootdisk lvm2 a--  118.75g 40.00m

[root@sklad ~]# vgs
  VG          #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree 
  vg_bootdisk   2   2   0 wz--n- 237.50g 80.00m
  vg_sklad01    4   1   0 wz--n-  10.92t     0 
  vg_sklad02    4   1   0 wz--n-  10.92t  2.73t

[root@sklad ~]# lvs
  LV         VG          Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lv_root    vg_bootdisk rwi-aor--- 102.70g                                    100.00          
  lv_swap    vg_bootdisk rwi-aor---  16.00g                                    100.00          
  lv_sklad01 vg_sklad01  rwi-aor---   8.19t                                    100.00          
  lv_sklad02 vg_sklad02  rwi-a-r---   5.46t                                    2.31
```

For some reason there is unallocated space in vg_sklad02 (the VG I'm working on). Shouldn't the -l 100%VG used all available space in the VG?

LV lv_sklad01 and lv_sklad02 should be the same size as they are created from the same drives, and as far as I recall I attempted to use the same create command.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my question, I've done this before and have a capture log of what I did to accomplish it two years ago. For some reason the identical lvcreate command didn't work. To get this LV create I had to specify the number of stripes using -i 3. So, the working command was:

```
lvcreate -i 3 --type raid5 -L 8.18T -n lv_sklad02 vg_sklad02
```

I guess something changed in updates to the LVM tools?

UPDATE

They did indeed make a change to LVM2. From rpm -q --changelog lvm2

```
* Fri Jul 29 2016 Peter Rajnoha <prajnoha@redhat.com> - 7:2.02.162-1
<...>
- Add allocation/raid_stripe_all_devices to reinstate previous behaviour.
- Create raid stripes across fixed small numbers of PVs instead of all PVs.
<...>
```

Nice to know I wasn't completely insane. :-) I RTFM'd, but not the right FM I guess. :-))